# php html show large dynamic table data in one tv dashboard

Tags: php, html, mysql, dashboard, display

I have one TV Dashboard (without touch). I want to display some information dynamically from database PHP/MySQL.
But here is a problem: when table rows exceed the height of screen i want to display automatically a second page and after 10 sec i want to auto go back on first page. All in loop mode. It is that possible?

Thank you.

I have code like this:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
       <tr>
        <th id="th_left">Ticket ID</th>
        <th id="th_left">Device Model</th>
        <th id="th_left">Client Name</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>



                    <?php
                       for ($j=0; $j<count($to_display_list); $j++) {
                           $a = $to_display_list[$j]->status_id;
                    ?>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><strong><?php echo $to_display_list[$j]->ticket_id ?></strong></td>
        <td><strong><?php echo $to_display_list[$j]->device_model ?></strong></td>
        <td><strong><?php echo $to_display_list[$j]->client_name ?></strong></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <?php           
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: a simple solution would be to create two pages and then do a meta refresh and direct to second page after 10 seconds, then the opposite back.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=page2.php">`

Comment: Ok? So does that mean it doesn't work? I don't understand the problem

Comment: How often does this data update? Will it update often enough that during the 10 seconds everything may be different? Will it be a problem if the last item on page1 is displayed on page2 also 10 seconds later because the data has been updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `<head>` place this:

```
<?php
// connect to database here and do what you need to get the variable $to_display_list

if(count($to_display_list)>=30){
    $page = $_GET['p'];
    if($page == "1"){
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=page.php?p=2">'; // replace page.php with your file name
    }else{
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=page.php?p=1">'; // replace page.php with your file name
    }
}else{ // less than 30 items, only display one page
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">';
}
?>
```

Then replace the part of the code you have above with:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
       <tr>
        <th id="th_left">Ticket ID</th>
        <th id="th_left">Device Model</th>
        <th id="th_left">Client Name</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>



 <?php 
   if(count($to_display_list)>=30){ 
       if($page == "1"){
           for ($j=0; $j<count($to_display_list)/2; $j++) {
           $a = $to_display_list[$j]->status_id;    
       }else{
           for ($j=count($to_display_list)/2; $j<count($to_display_list); $j++) {
              $a = $to_display_list[$j]->status_id;
           }
   }else{ // less than 30 items to display
       for ($j=0; $j<count($to_display_list); $j++) {
           $a = $to_display_list[$j]->status_id;
   }
 ?>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><strong><?php echo $to_display_list[$j]->ticket_id ?></strong></td>
        <td><strong><?php echo $to_display_list[$j]->device_model ?></strong></td>
        <td><strong><?php echo $to_display_list[$j]->client_name ?></strong></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <?php           
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

This uses the GET-method and meta refresh to update the page URL to ?p=1 or ?p=2 and reads a different part of the display list dependning on the page.
It will display half of the data on "page 1" and the other half on "page 2".

Comment: I'll try. Thank you. Keep in touch.

Comment: @Cristian-AngeloLungu One thing I noticed is that it will probably display "page 2" first, then start the loop. If that is a problem I can change it so it will start the loop on page 1

Comment: Thank you very much Andreas. Your solution is working.

Comment: @Cristian Try the new updated code to fix the < 30 items as you mention below.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     Andreas, I have another question:
>     If there is less rows, mean "<30", why I need to display page.php?p=2  ???
>     Below is my working code based on your answer (testing)
>     Thank you.
> ```

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php
        $page = $_GET['p'];
        if($page == "1"){
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=page.php?p=2">'; // replace page.php with your file name
        }else{
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=page.php?p=1">'; // replace page.php with your file name
        }
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>NUMBER</th>
                <th>MODEL</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>IN</th>
                <th>START</th>
                <th>PRICE</th>
                <th>WAITING</th>
                <th>DONE</th>
                <th>TIME</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php 
            if($page == "1"){
                for ($x=0; $x<30/2; $x++) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><strong><?php echo $x ?></strong></td>
                <td><strong>4545465</strong></td>
                <td><strong>ANY MODEL</strong></td>
                <td><strong>EMMET BROWN</strong></td>                       
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>X</td>
                <td></td>   
                <td>00:05:08</td>
            </tr>
        <?php } } else {
            for ($x=30/2; $x<30; $x++) {    
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><strong><?php echo $x ?></strong></td>
                <td><strong>4545465</strong></td>
                <td><strong>ANY MODEL</strong></td>
                <td><strong>EMMET BROWN</strong></td>                       
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>X</td>
                <td></td>   
                <td>00:05:08</td>
            </tr>
        <?php }} ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok so the magic number is 30? If it's more than 30 lines you only need one page to be displayed, if it's less than 30 then both pages is needed? In that case you will need to first connect to the database and count the number of entries, then if>30 do as above, else only refresh the page. That is what I think will work. I will edit my answer above with that so that you can see what I mean.

Comment: @Andreas, it's working. Yes, "30" is the magic number because "30" lines fit on the screen. When lines <= 30 need only one page, when lines > 30 need to split in 2 or 3 pages. Your script is ok. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: If you need three pages you only need to add a few lines and you get three pages. No problem :-)